# is "which" a complement in "which she wanted to be"?

Tags: relative-clauses, subject-complement

> Her sister has become a lawyer, **which** she wanted to be.

In the relative clause, "which she wanted to be", "which" serves as a complement.

Is my understanding right?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Seems to be so. I've just googled a little, and it does seem to function as a subject complement.
http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subject_complement.htm

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is right: *which* acts as complement to the infinitive *to be*.

Comment: Thank you. What about "Her sister has become a lawyer which she wanted to be"? Can "which" acts as complement in restrictive relative clause?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @April There is no internal difference between restrictive and nonrestrictive relative clauses. They differ only in their relation to the head clause.